AWS Cloudformation - Parameter conversion from string to number to use on my CIDRBlock
I am having this problem with my code wherein my parameter is set to Type: String performed a !Split on the 1st&2nd octet to use it in my CIDRBlock on my pub and priv subnet. I can upload it in my stack however when being created I am having this error:
"Resource handler returned message: "Value (CFN-FirstOctet-hrIoiM1a5WIJ.CFN-SecondOctet-yA4ydUpmLomI.x.x/x) for parameter cidrBlock is invalid. This is not a valid CIDR block."
 Parameter:
 VPCCidr:
    Type: String
    Description: 'IP address or range that is allowed'
    Default: x.x.x.x/x
    AllowedValues:
      - x.x.x.x/x
      - x.x.x.x/x
      - x.x.x.x/x

 FirstOctet:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Type: String
      Value: !Select [ 0, !Split [ ".", !Ref VPCCidr ]]

  SecondOctet:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Type: String
      Value: !Select [ 1, !Split [ ".", !Ref VPCCidr ]]

PublicSubnet:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !GetAZs '']
      CidrBlock: !Sub '${FirstOctet}.${SecondOctet}.x.x/x'
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: publicsubnet 
        - Key: Reach
          Value: public

Tried setting the Type: Number however I am getting this error:
"Properties validation failed for resource SecondOctet with message: [#/Type: Number is not a valid enum value]"
FirstOctet:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Type: Number
      Value: !Select [ 0, !Split [ ".", !Ref VPCCidr ]]

  SecondOctet:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Type: Number
      Value: !Select [ 1, !Split [ ".", !Ref VPCCidr ]]

I also did this already, but getting a parser error.
FirstOctet:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Type: Number
      Value:!Ref !Select [ 0, !Split [ ".", !Ref VPCCidr ]]

  SecondOctet:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Type: Number
      Value:!Ref !Select [ 1, !Split [ ".", !Ref VPCCidr ]]


After reading through the error you are encountering, my suggestion is that you simplify your approach by avoiding the use of AWS::SSM::Parameter for splitting the CIDR block octets. The errors you are seeing seem to arise from you trying to use AWS::SSM::Parameter for dynamic values, which isn't the correct use case for that resource type in CloudFormation.
Instead of creating separate parameters for FirstOctet and SecondOctet, you can dynamically split and select the octets of your VPCCidr inside the PublicSubnet resource without needing intermediate parameters.
Something like this:
Parameters:
  VPCCidr:
    Type: String
    Description: 'IP address or range that is allowed'
    Default: x.x.x.x/x
    AllowedValues:
      - x.x.x.x/x
      - x.x.x.x/x
      - x.x.x.x/x

Resources:
  PublicSubnet:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !GetAZs '']
      CidrBlock: !Sub "${!Select [0, !Split [ '.', !Ref VPCCidr ]]}.${!Select [1, !Split [ '.', !Ref VPCCidr ]]}.x.x/x"
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: publicsubnet
        - Key: Reach
          Value: public

This approach eliminates the need to define FirstOctet and SecondOctet as parameters, which I believe was causing parser errors.
Let me know if this helps resolve your issue!
If not, we can explore other possible options.

Hi! Thanks for this! however, it is not working as well, I've noticed that the whole syntax after "!Sub" was treated a whole string and the program inside is not executed to reflect the needed value were trying to achieve.
